# Is it possible to use multiple ::ng-deep identifiers to apply a style on a deeply nested component?

Tags: angular, sass

Say I have a DOM tree like so:

```
  <component1>
    <component2>
      <div>
        <component3>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <component4> Can a style be applied here using ng-deep?</component4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </component3>
      </div>
    </component2>
  </component1>
```

Is it possible to apply a style *from* a parent component (component1) on to the deeply nested 'component4'. Assuming all components are encapsulated..

Edit: I'm very aware this is not ideal in many ways, but question stands?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Basically, using `ng-deep` will break the shadow DOM, which will apply the css to every component being into it.

Meaning the following code added inside the `component1.scss` will change the background color of the `<component4>`

```
:host &::ng-deep component4 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

*As you said this is not ideal in many ways and I cannot recommend you to use `::ng-deep` since this is deprecated, please do use [encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) instead*